# How to export a pandas dataframe to Echarts dataset format?

Tags: pandas, export, echarts

[Echarts dataset format](https://apache.github.io/echarts-handbook/en/concepts/dataset/#define-data-in-dataset) looks like a CSV, but with additional square brackets. I was wondering how I could export a Pandas DataFrame directly to this format. Currently, I have to use an Emacs macro to turn exported CSV to this format.

Example of DataFrame:

```
|----------------+------+------+------|
| product        | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 |
|----------------+------+------+------|
| Matcha Latte   | 43.3 | 85.8 | 93.7 |
| Milk Tea       | 83.1 | 73.4 | 55.1 |
| Cheese Cocoa   | 86.4 | 65.2 | 82.5 |
| Walnut Brownie | 72.4 | 53.9 | 39.1 |
|----------------+------+------+------|
```

Example of expected output:

```
[
  ['product', 2015, 2016, 2017],
  ['Matcha Latte', 43.3, 85.8, 93.7],
  ['Milk Tea', 83.1, 73.4, 55.1],
  ['Cheese Cocoa', 86.4, 65.2, 82.5],
  ['Walnut Brownie', 72.4, 53.9, 39.1]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
out = [df.columns.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()
```

out:

```
[['product', '2015', '2016', '2017'],
 ['Matcha Latte', 43.3, 85.8, 93.7],
 ['Milk Tea', 83.1, 73.4, 55.1],
 ['Cheese Cocoa', 86.4, 65.2, 82.5],
 ['Walnut Brownie', 72.4, 53.9, 39.1]]
```

another approach

```
out = df.T.reset_index().T.values.tolist()
```

same result

---

**Example Code (df)**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'product': ['Matcha Latte', 'Milk Tea', 'Cheese Cocoa', 'Walnut Brownie'],
         '2015': [43.3, 83.1, 86.4, 72.4],
         '2016': [85.8, 73.4, 65.2, 53.9],
         '2017': [93.7, 55.1, 82.5, 39.1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Comment: @crocefisso If you don't want to create a DataFrame from the file and only return the data in the above format, use the following code. :  `out = pd.read_csv('your_file_path', header=None).values.tolist()`

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to export the result you provided (the variable `out`) into a file.